# C# Print numbers in 2 different intervals using do while only

Tags: c#, printing, while-loop, intervals, do-while

I need to write a program on C# using do while loop. 
Print numbers in intervals 66-21 and 77-99. Numbers from the first interval to decrease by 4 and these from the second interval to increase by 2. Use only one do-while loop and to continue while all numbers are printed from both intervals. If the numbers from one of the intervals are over print "Error" till the numbers of the second interval are printed. 
This is how I started:

```
int a = 66;
int b = 77;

do
{
    Console.WriteLine(a);
    a -= 4;
    Console.WriteLine(b);
    b += 2;

} while (a <= 22 && b >= 99);
```

Comment: And what is your problem on doing this? We won´t do your homework, you have to try something yourself.

Comment: Initialize b with value 77 should help: `int b = 77;`

Comment: Please provide a question on what your problem is

Comment: Okay, now we see what you´ve tried but still not what your problem with this code is.

Comment: your missing an if around the writelines to print 'Error', a must be greater or equal 22, and @Stefan is right, too

Comment: Hint: you need to evaluate a condition to know if one of the intervals has reached the "Error" point

Comment: Sorry,  I edit the code above. The first issue I got is that I print only the first numbers - 62 and 79 and the loop is ending I do not understand why

Comment: a must be GREATER or equal 22

Comment: ohhh.. I see now, thanks

Comment: **As a joke**, the following code fulfills the exercice but will make any teacher mad about you: `var enumerator = new int[] { 66, 77, 62, 79, 58, 81, 54, 83, 50, 85, 46, 87, 42, 89, 38, 91, 34, 93, 30, 95, 26, 97, 22, 99 }.GetEnumerator(); enumerator.MoveNext(); do { Console.WriteLine(enumerator.Current); } while (enumerator.MoveNext());`

Answer (score 0):

Following should help you. **Inline comments included.**

```
    int a = 66;
    int b = 77;  // Change here, you need to initialize it to 77
    do
    {
        if(a >= 22)   // Check condition for series 1 and print Error if condition is not met
        {
            Console.WriteLine(a);
            a -= 4;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error");
        }

        if( b <= 99) // Check condition for series 2 and print Error if condition is not met
        {
        Console.WriteLine(b);
        b += 2;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error");
        }

    } while (a >= 22 || b <= 99); // Loop Condition
```

You essentially need to add conditional checks to see if the condition has been met, and if not, print the required message. You would need checks for both the individual series